# How to search for all files containing this regex pattern?

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching

I'm trying to search for all files in my project containing the string "^{", followed by anything (including spaces, tabs, newlines, code, etc.), then "self." text by itself (there has to be nothing prepending the "self", i.e. not "blockself") and finally ending with "}".

This is what I've tried for now

`egrep -r (\^\{(.|\n|\t)*self\.(.|\n|\t)*\})`

but this doesn't work.

Examples of accepting text:

```
`^{ 
    // some random code
    // more code
    self.textView
  }`
```

I'd appreciate if I can get the entire unix command to do this.

Comment: _nothing prepending the "self"_ ? Could you explain that a little ?

Comment: As in not to have something `blockself.textview`, but this is allowed `self.textview` (spaces/tabs before the "self" are allowed).

Comment: Well in that case you just need to check for word boundary by adding `\b` before `self`. Your regex becomes `(\^\{(.|\n|\t)*\bself\.(.|\n|\t)*\})`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^\^\{[\w\W]*\bself\b[\w\W]*\}
```

> (\bself\b)

mean exact word (self) only not any other words as you want

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to match over multiple lines.  From my understanding, you cannot do this with just `grep`.

You can do this with [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (`-l` lists just the matching filename):

```
ag -l '\^\{[\s\S]*\bself\b[\s\S]*\}' *.txt
```

[pcregrep](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pcregrep1.html) can do this too (`-l` for just filenames and `-M` for multiline):

```
pcregrep -l -M '\^\{[\s\S]*\bself\b[\s\S]*\}' t.txt
```

The `\b` in these regular expressions represents a word boundary (space, period, etc.) so "blockself" won't match.

Comment: Can you quote chapter and verse, "you cannot do (multiple line match) with grep"?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` only searches for regexps on individual lines. You need `awk` to search for regexps that span lines, e.g. with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
find . -type f -print |
xargs awk -v RS='^$' '/\^{.*[[:space:]]self\..*}/{print FILENAME}'
```